# javax.xml.bind.JAXBException in java 11

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, maven, jaxb

Error found in logs :

```java
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: 
Could not create JAXBContext for class  Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.; 
nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath. - with linked exception: 
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
```

Added `POM` dependencies.

```xml
    <dependency> 
    <groupid>javax.xml.bind</groupid> 
    <artifactid>jaxb-api</artifactid> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
    <groupid>com.sun.xml.bind</groupid> 
    <artifactid>jaxb-core</artifactid> 
    <version>2.2.11</version> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
    <groupid>com.sun.xml.bind</groupid> 
    <artifactid>jaxb-impl</artifactid> 
    <version>2.2.11</version> 
    </dependency>
```

still finding jaxb error while running in kubernetes cluster.